# How can I Use the ternary operator in my code?

Tags: java

So my code should take the string and return the char in the middle of the String and if String has even number of elements it should return middle two

So my question is when I write my code like this

```
 public static String getMiddle(String word) {

        if(word == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            int length = word.length() / 2;
            if(word.length() % 2 == 0)
            {
                return "" + word.charAt(length-1) + word.charAt(length);
            }
            else
            {
                return "" + word.charAt(length);
            }

        }
```

It works fine but when I try to rewrite the code in just one statement like below ı got String index out of range: 2 error

```
    public static String getMiddle(String word) {


            int length = word.length() / 2;
            return "" + ((word.length() % 2 == 0)  ? (word.charAt(length-1)) +"" + (word.charAt(length+1)) :  word.charAt(length)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "[does not work](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) when word.length() is even"? Please use [edit] option and describe your problem in more details so people facing same problem would be able to find your question (and potential answers to it which is main purpose of this site...)

Comment: Note: in case of `char + char` `+` operator doesn't represent *concatenation* but *addition* (where result is sum of positions/indexes of characters in Unicode Table). In your original code you had `String + char + char` where `String + char` is concatenation resulting in String.

Comment: @Pshemo I edited the problem as detailed as I can thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator is different between string and char.

```
char two = '2'; // code point 50
char three = '3'; // code point 51

String twentyThree = ("" + '2') + '3'; // "23"
String charE = "" + ('2' + '3'); // "e", code point 101
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me fixing my code:))

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```java
return (word.length() % 2 == 0)
    ? "" + word.charAt(length-1) + word.charAt(length)
    : "" + word.charAt(length);
```

Comment: Thats because if string has odd elements there will be only one letter in the middle so it will return word.charAt(length) but if it has even numbers of elements it should return both charAt(length-1) and charAt(length)

Comment: I just noticed @Pshemo's comment, which mentions an issue I forgot to fix. I've changed my answer, it should be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

First, when you input a string into getMiddle(), it'll never be null. So you can change the first if statement to: `if (word.isEmpty()) { return null; }`. It's also advised not to return just null.

The reason your return statement returns an integer is because for the first value in the ternary operator, you're adding two characters which results in an integer. To fix the first value, change it to: `(word.charAt(length - 1) + "" + word.charAt(length + 1))`. The second value returns a char but the method indicates you're returning a String, so that's another error. To fix the second value, change it to `(word.charAt(length) + "")`

Comment: Thanks for your advice and your response  ı will be more carefull next time :)